# Nearest factorial given a number.

Tags: factorial

Hi suppose I have given a number lets say 344545.Is there a way to determine he nearest smallest factorial?

This is a Multiple choice question(one question 4 option).So what can be the fastest approach.A formal approach is also appreciated.

For 124 the nearest smallest factorial is 5!.so Ans is 5.

Comment: Someting like `unsigned lowfac(unsigned x) { unsigned n=1; while (x/=++n); return n-1; }`

Comment: What is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McQ by the way?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Good catch !

Comment: multiple choice questions

Comment: If the numbers are smallish, the fastest approach is to know the factorials of small positive integers (at least roughly), then you can see that e.g. $344545$ is roughly $9! = 362880$ at one glance.